# Combine same properties of two array of objects into one

Tags: javascript

I have an array of array of objects coming from backend.

```
[
   [
        {
            "question_id": "565",
            "option_type": "1",
            "question_image": "",
            "option_number": "4",
            "correct_answer": "d",
            "marks": "4",
            "language": "Hindi",
            "skill_id": "",
            "nos_id": "29",
            "question": "वितरण लाइन के लिए प्रयुक्त प्रतीक को पहचानें",
            "options": [
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "मौजूदा लाइन",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "योजनाबद्ध लाइन",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "भूमिगत लाइन",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "ओवरहेड लाइन",
                    "checked": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "question_id": "565",
            "option_type": "1",
            "question_image": "",
            "option_number": "4",
            "correct_answer": "d",
            "marks": "4",
            "language": "English",
            "skill_id": "",
            "nos_id": "29",
            "question": "Identify the symbol used for distribution line",
            "options": [
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "E O 1",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "E O 2",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "E O 3",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "E O 4",
                    "checked": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "question_id": "625",
            "option_type": "1",
            "question_image": "",
            "option_number": "4",
            "correct_answer": "b",
            "marks": "5",
            "language": "Hindi",
            "skill_id": "",
            "nos_id": "34",
            "question": "निम्नलिखित में से कौन सी न्यूनतम ऊंचाई है जिससे ऊपर सुरक्षा बेल्ट पहनना चाहिए?",
            "options": [
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "३ मीटर",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "२ मीटर  ",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "४ मीटर ",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "१ मीटर  ",
                    "checked": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "question_id": "625",
            "option_type": "1",
            "question_image": "",
            "option_number": "4",
            "correct_answer": "b",
            "marks": "5",
            "language": "English",
            "skill_id": "",
            "nos_id": "34",
            "question": "Which of the following is the minimum height at which a safety belt must be worn?  ",
            "options": [
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "English option 1",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "English option 2",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "English option 3",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "image": "",
                    "option": "English option 4",
                    "checked": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

I want to combine the inner array's objects and get one single array of objects and combine the questions and options into one object like below:

```
question: {
  english: "Identify the symbol used for distribution line"
  hindi: "वितरण लाइन के लिए प्रयुक्त प्रतीक को पहचानें"
}

"options": [
      {
          "image": "",
          "option": {
             "english: "English option 1",
             "hindi: "३ मीटर"
           },
          "checked": false
      },
      {
          "image": "",
          "option": {
             "english: "English option 2",
             "hindi: "२ मीटर  "
           },
          "checked": false
      },
      {
          "image": "",
          "option": {
             "english: "English option 3",
             "hindi: "४ मीटर "
           },
          "checked": false
      },
      {
          "image": "",
          "option": {
             "english: "English option 4",
             "hindi: "१ मीटर  "
           },
          "checked": false
      }
  ]
```

Here's what I have tried. Here questions which I am mapping is the one I am getting from backend.

```
const combinedArray = questions.map((question) => {
  let combined = {};
  let questionObj = {};
  let optionsObj = {};
  question.forEach((languageQ) => {
     combined.question_id = languageQ.question_id;
     combined.u_question_id = languageQ.u_question_id;
     combined.option_type = languageQ.option_type;
     combined.question_image = languageQ.question_image;
     combined.option_number = languageQ.option_number;
     combined.correct_answer = languageQ.correct_answer;
     combined.marks = languageQ.marks;
     combined.skill_id = languageQ.skill_id;
     combined.nos_id = languageQ.nos_id;
     
     if (languageQ.language === 'English') {
            questionObj.english = languageQ.question;
     } else if (languageQ.language === 'Hindi') {
            questionObj.hindi = languageQ.question;
     }
     combined.question = questionObj;
     
     
     languageQ.options.forEach((option) => {
            if (languageQ.language === 'English') {
                optionsObj.english = option.option;
        } else if (languageQ.language === 'Hindi') {
          optionsObj.hindi = option.option;
        }
        option.option = optionsObj;
     });
     
     combined.options = languageQ.options;
  });
  
  return combined;
});
```

I am successfully able to get a single array of objects with question coming as combined like I want but options are not correct. It's only taking the last item of the options array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forEach intead (or reduce maybe).

```js
var questions = [
   [
    {
        "question_id": "565",
        "option_type": "1",
        "question_image": "",
        "option_number": "4",
        "correct_answer": "d",
        "marks": "4",
        "language": "Hindi",
        "skill_id": "",
        "nos_id": "29",
        "question": "वितरण लाइन के लिए प्रयुक्त प्रतीक को पहचानें",
        "options": [
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "मौजूदा लाइन",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "योजनाबद्ध लाइन",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "भूमिगत लाइन",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "ओवरहेड लाइन",
                "checked": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "question_id": "565",
        "option_type": "1",
        "question_image": "",
        "option_number": "4",
        "correct_answer": "d",
        "marks": "4",
        "language": "English",
        "skill_id": "",
        "nos_id": "29",
        "question": "Identify the symbol used for distribution line",
        "options": [
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "E O 1",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "E O 2",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "E O 3",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "E O 4",
                "checked": false
            }
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "question_id": "625",
        "option_type": "1",
        "question_image": "",
        "option_number": "4",
        "correct_answer": "b",
        "marks": "5",
        "language": "Hindi",
        "skill_id": "",
        "nos_id": "34",
        "question": "निम्नलिखित में से कौन सी न्यूनतम ऊंचाई है जिससे ऊपर सुरक्षा बेल्ट पहनना चाहिए?",
        "options": [
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "३ मीटर",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "२ मीटर  ",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "४ मीटर ",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "१ मीटर  ",
                "checked": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "question_id": "625",
        "option_type": "1",
        "question_image": "",
        "option_number": "4",
        "correct_answer": "b",
        "marks": "5",
        "language": "English",
        "skill_id": "",
        "nos_id": "34",
        "question": "Which of the following is the minimum height at which a safety belt must be worn?  ",
        "options": [
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "English option 1",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "English option 2",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "English option 3",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "option": "English option 4",
                "checked": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
];


function transformQuestion (questions) {
  let questionMap = {};
  let result = [];

  questions.forEach((question) => {
    question.forEach((languageQ) => {

      let combined = {};
      let id = ""+languageQ.question_id;
  
      if (questionMap.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        combined = questionMap[id];
      } else {
        questionMap[id] = combined;

        combined.question_id = languageQ.question_id;
        combined.u_question_id = languageQ.u_question_id;
        combined.option_type = languageQ.option_type;
        combined.question_image = languageQ.question_image;
        combined.option_number = languageQ.option_number;
        combined.correct_answer = languageQ.correct_answer;
        combined.marks = languageQ.marks;
        combined.skill_id = languageQ.skill_id;
        combined.nos_id = languageQ.nos_id;
      }
  
      combined.question = combined.question || {};
      combined.question[languageQ.language] = languageQ.question;

      combined.options = combined.options || [];

      if (combined.options.length > 0) {
        languageQ.options.forEach((option, ndx) => {
          combined.options[ndx].option[languageQ.language] = option.option;
        });
      } else {
        combined.options = languageQ.options.map((option) => {
          let opt = {};
          opt[languageQ.language] = option.option;
          return {"image": option.image
                 ,"option": opt 
                 ,"checked": option.checked };
        });
      }
    });  
  });  

  Object.keys(questionMap).forEach((key) => {
    if (questionMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      result.push(questionMap[key]); 
    }
  });

  return result;  
}

console.log(transformQuestion(questions));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.